# java legal identifiers

Tags: java, scjp

I'm readind an eBook that sais:

```
int :b;
int e#;
```

are not legal identifiers, but I don't understand why ":" and "#" are not legal tokens.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You should have to read  *Java Language Specification*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) says so:

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.

```
Identifier:
    IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral

IdentifierChars:
    JavaLetter
    IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit

JavaLetter:
    any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)

JavaLetterOrDigit:
    any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
```

> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method
>   Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true.
>
> The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters
>   A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical
>   reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) and dollar sign ($, or
>   \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated
>   source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy
>   systems.
>
> The "Java digits" include the ASCII digits 0-9 (\u0030-\u0039).
>
> Letters and digits may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set,
>   which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today,
>   including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This
>   allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are
>   written in their native languages.

Answer (score 1):

Valid identifiers are defined in the [JLS #3.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8). In particular:

> A "Java letter" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int) returns true.
>
> A "Java letter-or-digit" is a character for which the method Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(int) returns true.

Those two lines output false, which makes your two identifiers invalid:

```
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(':'));
System.out.println(Character.isJavaIdentifierPart('#'));
```

Note that valid identifiers include A-Z, a-z, _, $ but also many "exotic" characters. For example, this is a valid identifier:

```
int a_£àèƒ¥;
```

Comment: Yep. First time I saw greek letters being used as variables in a math function, I did a double-take.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

```
An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, 
the first of which must be a Java letter.
```

..

```
The "Java letters" include uppercase and lowercase ASCII Latin letters A-Z (\u0041-\u005a), 
and a-z (\u0061-\u007a), and, for historical reasons, the ASCII underscore (_, or \u005f) 
and dollar sign ($, or \u0024). The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated 
source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.
```

Comment: Java letters include those, but there's plenty of other valid characters.